# Can I use Firebase Crashlytics with worker service to log exceptions

Tags: .net, windows, firebase, windows-services, firebase-crash-reporting

I am working on Windows Service development(which runs in bg in windows machine). To log/store exceptions I want to use **`Firebase Crashlytics`** so that anyone can access it from anywhere.

Not sure if Crsahlytics support web applications too.

Please suggest?

Comment: No, Firebase Crashlytics does not currently support web applications. You might want to try a different error reporting tool, such as https://sentry.io/

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes - You can write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately Firebase Crashlytics does not currently support web applications.

You might want to try an alternative error reporting tool, such as [sentry.io](https://sentry.io).